# Getting ttyS0: 1 input overrun(s)

Tags: java, c

I am getting "ttyS0: 1 input overrun(s)" (this error is seen in Java application logs) on performing Serial communication between an application running on Java platform and another application running on c.

Can anyone explain on which scenarios this error can occur, or how to re create this error.
I am getting this error sporadically.

Answer (score -1):

Serial ports are tied to hardware devices and have a maximum speed imposed by a wire protocol and hardware settings. Your library is probably getting more info to send than the serial port can handle given its speed, hence the "input overrun".

Comment: Is there any Linux command with which flow rate of port can be decrease so that it can reproduced in normal message exchange.

Comment: `stty` is the tool to display or change the settings, but a serious library will probably override everything so you probably need to find a way to change it in your library.

Comment: Other way around, there is a flow to host serial port which application doesn't handle in time.